# Setting up Jenkins git tracking with networked git repository

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to set up Jenkins git repository tracking. The bare git repository I am trying to track exists on a networked drive on another server which I would normally be able to access using something similar to this; \host\path\to\repo

However, upon trying to use this as a repository URL in Jenkins, I get the following error; (I have subbed the actual URL for a replacement that maintains slashes.

Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe ls-remote -h \\host\path\to\repo HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: '\host\path\to\repo\' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

The repository does exist and I can access and clone from it normally. Am I missing a Jenkins set up stage or am I doing something wrong with the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being windows permissions. Once I was running jenkins under it's own user account instead of the local system, everything worked and Jenkins seemed to have access to network drives.